# How to identify elements in the DOM to use in click button event?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Trying to learn some Javascript now that I have a few months of Python under my belt. Having trouble with HTML elements on a page which uses Javascript (not sure that is the right wording).

I have a simple Chrome Extension which I am trying to tell it to click a button when the page loads.

The DOM shows this code more or less:

```
<body class="skin-mark toolbar-open  table-active">
    <div class="tile-tables"></div>
</body>
```

My attempt at clicking the button has been multiple ways similar to this:

```
document.querySelector('#tile-tables').click();
```

Any help in understanding the process here and what I am doing wrong would be great! Thanks in advance! Feel free to correct me at any place and I will fix my language.

Comment: Which is the "button" that you want to click on? The `span`?

Comment: ah, yes. The button is "Join". I thought I had needed to use the `<div id>` to identify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `getElementById` you have to pass an element's *id* to it. There is only one element with an `id` in your HTML, the outer `userActActions-51` - so, if you were to select by ID first, you would do

```
document.getElementById('userActActions-51')
```

and then you would access the second nested child:

```
const userActions = document.getElementById('userActActions-51');
const span = userActions.children[0].children[0];
span.click();
```

But it would be more convenient to use `querySelector` for this, which will allow you to use a selector string to select the `span` descendant of the element with the id `userActActions-51` at once:

```
document.querySelector('#userActActions-51 span').click();
```

If the element might not exist, then make sure that it exists before trying to click on it:

```
const span = document.querySelector('#userActActions-51 span');
if (span) span.click();
```

Comment: Now, I shortened up the code a lot but there are many children under the `'userActActions-51'`. I assume that they are listed in order and if it was the fifth child I would write `const span = userActions.children[4].children[4];`?

Comment: That's what you'd use if it's the fifth child of the fifth child of `#userActActions-51`, please post the *actual* HTML in the question

Comment: I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null`. I am going to go out on a limb and say that if `userActActions-51` is the child of another element then I would have to go further and say `const span = otherElement.children[0].children[0].children[13];` or something similar?

Comment: Sure, though it would be much better to use a selector string instead, that way you can select it immediately rather than having to repeatedly use Javascript property access

Comment: Okay, so I have tried everything I could and can't get it to work which means I clearly have no understanding of it. I edited my original post to reflect a button near the top of the page which I cannot get to work either. Could you show my how that would look?

Comment: You don't have anything with an `id` there, so you don't want to use `#` in `querySelector` (which indicates an `id`). `tile-tables` is a class, which is indicated with `.` in a selector string - if it's the only one in the document, you can select it with `document.querySelector('.tile-tables')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181312/discussion-between-6seven8-and-certainperformance).